# Extract the rest of the rows within a group / factor in R

Tags: arrays, r, dataframe, group-by, dplyr

I have the following dataframe:

```
x <- data.frame("A"=c(rep(4,3),rep(7,4),rep(2,2)),
                "B"=c("Q","Y"," ","F","Q"," ","Z","Q","C"),
                "C"=seq(1:9))
```

- `A` being my grouping variable / factor
- `B` the status flag I'll strart subsetting after its first appearance.
  I've managed to subset a ***fixed*** amount of rows after by just adding the amount of rows to subset to B's indices where "Q" appears:

Something like this: `x[c(which(x$B=="Q"),which(x$B=="B")+1),]`

"+1" because I was just interested in the first row after "Q" occurs.

Now I need the ***rest of the rows within each group*** after "Q" occurs (including Q's row),  and I been banging my head against my desk trying to figure out how to do this with the `dplyr` package with grouped tibbles... hence I'm here.

Please help?

------ EDIT -----

This seemed to have worked

```
x %>% group_by(A) %>% filter(row_number()>=which.max(B=="Q"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr` you may run the following code:

```
mydf <- data.frame("A"=c(rep(4,3),rep(7,4),rep(2,2)),
                "B"=c("Q","Y"," ","F","Q"," ","Z","Q","C"),
                "C"=seq(1:9))

library(tidyverse)
mydf %>%
    group_by(A) %>% 
    mutate(selector=case_when(
        B=="Q" ~ 1
    )) %>% 
    fill(...=selector,.direction="down") %>% 
    filter(selector==1) %>% 
    select(-selector)) %>% 
    arrange(C,A)
```

and this is the result:

```
      A B         C
  <dbl> <fct> <int>
1  4.00 Q         1
2  4.00 Y         2
3  4.00 " "       3
4  7.00 Q         5
5  7.00 " "       6
6  7.00 Z         7
7  2.00 Q         8
8  2.00 C         9
```

Comment: This gave me the exact result I was looking for. Thank you very much for taking your time to help!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
q_rows <- row.names(subset(x, B == 'Q')) # rows where Q occurs 
list_of_frames <- list()
for(i in 1:length(q_rows)) {
    q_start <- as.numeric(q_rows[i]);
    q_group <- as.numeric(x[q_start,c('A')])
    group_frame <- subset(x[q_start:nrow(x),], A == q_group)
    list_of_frames[i] <- list(group_frame)
    }
```

**list_of_frames**

[image]